# High CPU load in WSO2 EI 6.6.0

Tags: java, wso2, heap-memory, cpu-usage, wso2-enterprise-integrator

We have deployed our WSO2 EI 6.6.0 solution on a RHEL 8 Linux machines. We see that WSO2 java process is consuming more CPU load and they don't get normal, and once we restart all gets 0. We have tried changing the config files but still no luck and below is the reference.

Java Parameters :  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Xss256m

passthru-http.properties.

```
# Copyright (c) 2016, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved.
#
# WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
# Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
# in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

## This file contains the configuration parameters used by the Pass-through HTTP transport

## Pass-through HTTP transport specific tuning parameters
http.socket.timeout=180000

#worker_pool_size_core=400
#worker_pool_size_max=500
worker_pool_size_core=100
worker_pool_size_max=100
worker_thread_keepalive_sec=60
#worker_pool_queue_length=-1
#io_threads_per_reactor=2
io_buffer_size=16384
#http.max.connection.per.host.port=32767

# This property is crucial for automated tests
http.socket.reuseaddr=true

## Other parameters
#http.user.agent.preserve=false
#http.server.preserve=true
http.headers.preserve=Content-Type
#http.connection.disable.keepalive=false
rest.dispatcher.service=__MultitenantDispatcherService
# URI configurations that determine if it requires custom rest dispatcher
rest_uri_api_regex=\\w+://.+:\\d+/t/.*|\\w+://.+\\w+/t/.*|^(/t/).*
rest_uri_proxy_regex=\\w+://.+:\\d+/services/t/.*|\\w+://.+\\w+/services/t/.*|^(/services/t/).*

# Message size validation based on the message size in bytes.
#message.size.validation.enabled=true
#valid.max.message.size.in.bytes=81920
```

Below are our threads :
"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1" #157 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5582.51ms elapsed=87405.70s tid=0x00007f8600af1800 nid=0x8181 runnable  [0x00007f7fbffe6000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e7ad2750> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e7ad26f8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2" #158 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=783854.24ms elapsed=87405.63s tid=0x00007f8600942800 nid=0x8182 runnable  [0x00007f7faffe5000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.drain(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.clearInterrupt(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:266)
- locked <0x00000000e7ad4af0> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.processEvents(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:203)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:137)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e7ad29a0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e7ad2948> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-3" #159 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5569.42ms elapsed=87405.60s tid=0x00007f86010fa800 nid=0x8183 runnable  [0x00007f7f9ffe4000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e7ad2eb8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e7ad2c48> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4" #160 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5519.55ms elapsed=87405.52s tid=0x00007f8600b35000 nid=0x8184 runnable  [0x00007f7f8ffe3000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e57ad7f8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e57ad808> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-5" #161 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=763010.04ms elapsed=87405.49s tid=0x00007f8600dbf800 nid=0x8185 runnable  [0x00007f7f7ffe2000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e57ada88> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e3029c18> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-6" #162 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5530.21ms elapsed=87405.41s tid=0x00007f86004d3000 nid=0x8186 runnable  [0x00007f7f6ffe1000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e57adc20> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e57adc30> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-7" #163 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5558.50ms elapsed=87405.36s tid=0x00007f8600040800 nid=0x8187 runnable  [0x00007f7f5ffe0000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e57ade60> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e57ade70> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-8" #164 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5556.33ms elapsed=87405.34s tid=0x00007f8600b42000 nid=0x8188 runnable  [0x00007f7f4ffdf000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e57ae0a0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e57ae0b0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-9" #165 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5540.08ms elapsed=87405.26s tid=0x00007f8601149000 nid=0x8189 runnable  [0x00007f7f3ffde000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e57aed70> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e57aed80> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-10" #166 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5562.65ms elapsed=87405.19s tid=0x00007f8600177800 nid=0x818a runnable  [0x00007f7f2ffdd000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e57aee40> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e57aee50> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-11" #167 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5535.88ms elapsed=87405.18s tid=0x00007f86005ac000 nid=0x818b runnable  [0x00007f7f1ffdc000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e57af218> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e57af228> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-12" #168 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5551.89ms elapsed=87405.15s tid=0x00007f86015da800 nid=0x818c runnable  [0x00007f7f0ffdb000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e57b0120> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e57b0130> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"http-nio-9763-BlockPoller" #169 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1087.26ms elapsed=87404.95s tid=0x00007f8649348800 nid=0x818d runnable  [0x00007f7efffda000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.16/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:124)
- locked <0x00000000e57b0370> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
- locked <0x00000000e57b0380> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.16/SelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.run(NioBlockingSelector.java:313)

"http-nio-9763-exec-1" #170 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.13ms elapsed=87404.81s tid=0x00007f8649352000 nid=0x818f waiting on condition  [0x00007f7eeffd9000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000000e57b0550> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.16/LockSupport.java:194)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.16/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@11.0.16/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:107)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"http-nio-9763-exec-2" #171 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.17ms elapsed=87404.77s tid=0x00007f8649353000 nid=0x8190 waiting on condition  [0x00007f7edffd8000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000000e57b0550> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.16/LockSupport.java:194)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.16/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@11.0.16/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:107)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"http-nio-9763-exec-3" #172 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.13ms elapsed=87404.66s tid=0x00007f8649354800 nid=0x8192 waiting on condition  [0x00007f7ecffd7000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000000e57b0550> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.16/LockSupport.java:194)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.16/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@11.0.16/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:107)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

"http-nio-9763-exec-4" #173 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.14ms elapsed=87404.64s tid=0x00007f8649356800 nid=0x8193 waiting on condition  [0x00007f7ebffd6000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.16/Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000000e57b0550> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.16/LockSupport.java:194)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.16/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@11.0.16/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:107)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.16/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.16/Thread.java:829)

Comment: Do you try to run with Java 8 instead of Java 11.0.16? I am asking, because there was some issues with C2 compiler in 11.0.16 fixed in 11.0.16.1, but maybe it is worth to try Java8. That also  maybe useful;  [JVM C1, C2 Compiler Thread: High CPU Consumption][1]
  [1]: https://dzone.com/articles/jvm-c1-c2-compiler-thread-high-cpu-consumption

Answer (score 0):

Shall we use [this](https://gist.github.com/bsenduran/02e8bf024fcaaa7707a6bb2321e097a8) script to capture a few thread dumps and thread usage dumps when you are observing the issue? Then you can follow [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/setup/deployment/troubleshooting_deployment/) documentation to identify which threads are consuming more CPU. Share the high CPU-consuming thread and stack trace here.

Comment: We have added the threads in the main question.

Comment: I'm not seeing any unusual behaviour in the threads. Can you attach one thread dump and thread usage dump to see

Comment: Below is the link to download the files. Day by day the CPU goes up and never comes down until restart. We use our api hardly once a day. Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sBtmZq8Jg66m6nZ1ln9UA99dhRs9tyV8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: checked the dumps and identified that HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher threads consume more CPU. WSO2 released several fixes to resolve similar kind of issues that happens due to a java upgrade. https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/8908. If you have a subscription you need to update the product or use a java version below 1.8_261

Comment: Thanks for your articles we went through the articles and updated the dafault jar post which my issue is resolved.